# Razor Component OnClick not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to add a Razor Component in my MVC WebApp. Rendering the Component works fine, but when I'm clicking the button, the Method I want to use as the OnClick event doesn't get called and all the solutions I found for similar questions don't work for me.

This is the Razor Component:

```
@using Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

@{ foreach (var item in order.ObjectConfigs.ConfigList)
    {
        <button class="button" type="button" @onclick="() => SelectConfig(item.fileName)">@item.FileName</button>

    }

}
@{ if (objectConfiguration != null)
    {
        <ConfigureObject ObjectConfiguration="objectConfiguration"></ConfigureObject>

    }
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public OrderIntern order { get; set; }
    public ObjectConfiguration objectConfiguration;
    bool loadConfigView;

    void SelectConfig(string fileName)
    {
        objectConfiguration = order.ObjectConfigs.ConfigList.First(e => e.FileName == fileName);
        
    }
}
```

Here I want to use the Component:

```
@model OrderIntern
@{

}
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<ObjectList>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered, new { order = Model }))

<button class="button-left" type="button">Zurück</button>
<button class="button-right" type="button">Weiter</button>
```

One of the solutions i found is to add _Imports.razor, but I already have it.

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using System.IO
@using Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
@using System.Linq
```

I also added Blazor in the ConfigureServices and the Configure Method in the startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            });
        }
```

I'm using .Net 6.0 for my project.
I hope I didn't forget important information, if so just ask.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT1:
I changed the Code of the Component a little, because I need the OnClick Method with a parameter. I only removed it to find out if this is causing the problem.

EDIT2:
I created a new MVC App where I just added a razor Component with a button. The OnClick method doesn't do anything but I used a breakpoint to see if the method is called but still nothing.
I created a Github repository so you can try it yourself.
https://github.com/courtmountain/MvcRazorComponent

Here is how i created the project.

1. started with an Webapplication with MVC

2.I added `builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();` and `app.MapBlazorHub();` to the `Program.cs`
(It seems lite they merged the `startup.cs` into the `Programm.cs`. I also recreated my actual project with this changes but it still doesn't work)

3. I created a razor component with only a button and an OnClick function in it and called it in the `Index.cs` of the HomeController

Edit3:
I've missed the `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` in my new project and now it works. I hope I will find my mistake now.

Edit4:
The Razor component works fine, but only when I'm calling it from the index View of the Home Comtroller. If I try to use any component in an different view, the button onclick stops working.

Comment: Maybe you can try moving your `foreach` loop outside the razor clause (the section wrapped with `@{}`) and just use `@foreach` for iterating your button or components

Comment: is there any error you are getting?

Comment: Are you actually using breakpoints to determine that you're not hitting the method?  Or is it just that your UI is not updating like you are expecting?  IIRC `void` methods don't automatically call `StateHasChanged`, so either call it or use a `Task` method.

Comment: I don't get any errors.

Comment: I'm using breakpoints but i never hit them when I click the button.

Comment: Use `F12` to see  is any error  in the console ?

Comment: @Courtmountain Did you try what @Raffy suggested? `@{ }` can be removed around both `foreach` and `if` statement. Even if it's not causing the problem it will probably make your code cleaner and more readable.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos i tried removing the {} but it makes no difference

Comment: @Courtmountain have you added `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` to the `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've added a minimal reproducible example. I hope i did everything right

Comment: I don't see `blazor.server.js` or a Blazor package.   [This walk-through](https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/) could be a bit dated but do check the main points.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I forgot the blazor.server.js after i added it the n click worked. I also realized, that the components in my actual project are working to but only if i call them in the index.cs of the homecontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the case someone else is having this problem in the future:

I had two mistakes.
-I had to add `<base href="~/"/>` in the head of my Layout.cs so the `blazor.server.js` can be found
-There was a List of IFormFile in my model, which caused a problem when I tried to transfer it to my razor component

I realised this when I looked at the console of the browser. There I found this error: `Error: The list of component records is not valid.` after that my WebApp lost the connection to the `blazor.server.js`.

Answer (score -1):

Your button code should be like this, if you want to call C# code

```
<button class="button" type="button" @onclick=@(() => SelectConfig())>@item.FileName</button>
```

Comment: How exactly is this supposed to help?  You only replaced the (recommended) `""` with `()`.

Comment: How about @ as well

Comment: The original code should have compiled (and worked). Nothing wrong with it.